# Git fails to commit new project to GitHub "refusing to merge unrelated histories"

Tags: git, github

Git refuses to commit a new project to GitHub

I tried everything possible

It is not 1 specific error, there seem to be multiple errors

What commands do I need to type to make this commit?

Here is the console printout, edited for internet

```
D:\>cd D:\Projects\TestProject

D:\Projects\TestProject>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/Projects/TestProject/.git/

D:\Projects\TestProject>git add .

D:\Projects\TestProject>git commit -m "First Commit"
[master (root-commit) 525f262] First Commit
 17 files changed, 976 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 TestProject.sln
 create mode 100644 TestProject/App.config
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Form1.Designer.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Form1.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Form1.resx
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/Resources.resx
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/Settings.settings

D:\Projects\TestProject>git remote add origin https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject

D:\Projects\TestProject>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject (push)

D:\Projects\TestProject>git push origin master
To https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

First failed push, following directions to `git pull`

```
D:\Projects\TestProject>git pull
warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


D:\Projects\TestProject>git push origin master
To https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

D:\Projects\TestProject>git pull --rebase
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

D:\Projects\TestProject>git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

D:\Projects\TestProject>git branch
* master

D:\Projects\TestProject>git pull origin master
From https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

D:\Projects\TestProject>git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

D:\Projects\TestProject>git pull
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Moved the added files out of the directory

```
D:\Projects\TestProject>git clone https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject
Cloning into 'TestProject'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
```

Moved the added files back into the directory

```
D:\Projects\TestProject>git add .

D:\Projects\TestProject>git commit -m "Second Commit"
[master 41b46fc] Second Commit
 18 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 TestProject.sln
 create mode 100644 TestProject/App.config
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Form1.Designer.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Form1.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Form1.resx
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/Resources.resx
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
 create mode 100644 TestProject/Properties/Settings.settings
 create mode 100644 TestProject/README.md

D:\Projects\TestProject>git push
To https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/TestAccount/TestProject'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

D:\Projects\TestProject>git pull
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge origin origin/master
```